# What are the pros and cons of ui-sref?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-sref

I'm starting to work on a legacy project using Angular `1.5` and it uses both `href` and `ui-sref`.

I don't really see the point of using the latter, especially for top menu.

#### Example

**menu.html**

```
<a ui-sref="expense-home">
    <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
    <translate>Expenses claims</translate>
</a>
```

**app.route.js**

```
.state('expense-home', {
    url: '/expenses',
    template: '<expenses-home></expenses-home>',
})
```

#### Question

Could you provide some pros and cons of `ui-sref` and scenarios where it is useful?

Comment: If you want to use href then use ng-href instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pros:

#### 1. url abstraction

The most important gain from using `ui-sref` is that you work on state name which is some abstraction over the url address.

So when using `ui-sref` you're really independent of the actual urls, and e.g. if you ever decide to change them (which, belive me, really happens ;) ) you just change the `.state` configuration and all urls within your app change.

This way you can also possibly localize your urls, and e.g. in some instances have `ui-sref="contact"` pointed at `/contact-us` while in others to `/kontaktiere`.

#### 2. independence from parameters order

The other thing is that when you have to pass several parameters into your url (say, the url definition is `users/:userId/albums/:albumId`) you don't need to remember/care about the parameters' order and just use the object:

```
<a ui-sref="albumDetails({userId: user.id, albumId: album})">
  {{album.name}}
</a>
```

#### 3. uninterpolated value for href attr prevention

Other than that, as the other answer pointed out, when you use `href` directly, there is a moment in your app's lifecycle when what the browser sees is `<a href="{{ sth }}">` - Angular hasn't yet interpolated the expression - if you'd click on such link it'd try to point you to something like `http://example.com/%7B%7B%20sth%20%7D%7D`. 
`ng-href`, `ui-sref` (and most noticeably `ng-src` on images) prevents from this to happen since they are not something that gets interpreted by browsers.

### Cons:

As for the cons - I have yet to encounter one :)

Answer (score 1):

href (as well as ng-href) generates an actual link which is interpreted by the browser (and it can be any URL, even external URLs) and ui-sref is processed by javascript.